# Java 1.7 if statement on result of declaring and initialising a variable with scope of the if statement

Tags: java

Yarh- this is hard to explain. Is it possible to so something like this:

```
static String nullOrLastname(String name)
{
    if(name.equals("jonas")) return "marshen";
    return null;
} 

if( (String lastname=nullOrLastname("jonas")) != null)
{   
     System.out.println(lastname);
}
```

This works, but is ugly etc.

```
for(String  lastname = nullOrLastname("jonas");lastname !=null;lastname=null)
{
    System.out.println(lastname);
}
```

Is there a better way?
What is the name of what I want to do? 
Did I use the correct words in the headline?

Comment: You're not even comparing String the correct way...

Comment: Why would someone do that, this sounds like an X/Y problem, what is your goal?

Comment: @Tunaki, you're misunderstanding the question. Look at my answer.

Comment: @shmosel `if(name=="jonas")`. And I didn't understand the rest.

Comment: @shmosel Strings need to be compared with `.equals()` in `nullOrLastname()`.

Comment: A much better solution is available in JDK 8: Optional.  Time to upgrade.  JDK 7 has passed the end of its support life.  Best to get up to speed on the current production version and learn its new features.

Comment: @Tunaki, oops, my bad. Thought you were referring to the second part.

Comment: @shmosel Agree, that's not the main question (and this is why I didn't vote close as duplicate). But that's worth mentioning though.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following if you don't want scope leak.

```
{
    String lastname = nullOrLastname("jonas");
    if (lastname != null)
        System.out.println(lastname);
}
```

In Java 8 you would use an Optional and turn this into a one liner.

```
static Optional<String> nullOrLastname(String name)    {
    return Optional.ofNullable("jonas".equals(name) ? "marshen" : null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    nullOrLastname("jonas").ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Optional is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable first:

```
String lastname;
if( (lastname=nullOrLastname("jonas")) != null)
{   
     System.out.println(lastname);
}
```

Comment: You can put this inside a `{` and `}` to avoid scope leak.

Comment: A much better solution is available in JDK 8: Optional.  Time to upgrade.